# Is there any GUI to see the chain from ldb database: view blocks, wallets, etc?

Tags: private-blockchain, gui

Is that true: files with *.ldb = LevelDB files?

So i looked for LevelDB GUI managers and launched some of them to look through my local test chain:

1. [levelui](https://github.com/0x00A/levelui) (can't launch)
2. [Keylord](https://protonail.com/) (launch but get strange ureadable
   view of chain)
3. [DB Browser for Sqlite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) (not for this, but also open
   ldb with answering me for db password, where it get - didn't know)

All solutions which i tried - bad.
Also i look at [ganache](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache), but this is not that i need.

I want to find a way to look readable raw blocks in local test chain, to understand how wallets, contracts, blocks look. Maybe anyone know how it do much better - give some advice please. I found so-so example which more closest to my problem: [block 911516 in etherchain](https://etherchain.org/api/block/911516/tx), but with maybe some info, not with all.

thx a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any GUI to see the chain from ldb database: view blocks,
>   wallets, etc?

Probably not, but it'd be an interesting project to put together.

The problem is that within the database, the data is encoded using Ethereum's [RLP](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/RLP) encoding, so any tool would need to be able to strip this off. None of the tools you've mentioned above have any knowledge of this encoding, so...

> Keylord (launch but get strange ureadable view of chain)...

...you end up with this, which is presumably the RLP-encoded data.

The following walk-through will give you an idea of how things are laid out, and how to go about reading them, but it's all done in Nodejs, rather than through a GUI: [Using Ethereum's Tries with Nodejs](https://wanderer.github.io/ethereum/nodejs/code/2014/05/21/using-ethereums-tries-with-node/)

Comment: hm.. also, yes i'm looking that article with Nodejs right now